# PHP User Profile / if user has access

Tags: php, settings, profile

I wanna ask something about User (who registered) profile settings. For example in many forums you can choose your privacy settings from settings page. I mean "do not show my e-mail address or my name etc.

Let me explain some variables:

`$_SESSION['username']` is username whom logged in.

$username : profile page of someone (for example: profile.php/username) - i used get method for this.

I want to show a button if current user(who logged in and viewing someone's profile) has an access to see it or not.

Here we go:

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != $username)
{
//do not show button
}else{
//show button}
```

I don't want to use `display:none` or `visibility hidden`. Because they can change from source code and i didn't like it. Can i make these settings with private function? I need a solution with examples.
Thanks.

Comment: Just echo the button in the else clause: echo '<input type="button">';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the logic determining if user has or has not access. If it's just that simple condition comparing two variables, you can simply show the button via `echo` command:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] === $username) {
    echo '<button>Profile page</button>';
}
```

Comment: I'm laughing now really :D how couldn't i realise that. Thanks.